# How to find where a package is installed by pacman?

Tags: archlinux, package-management, pacman-package-manager

I'm installing c++ boost library by `pacman -Ss boost-libs`. After installation, I want to know where my package is installed in my system.

Is there any pacman command for doing so?

Comment: Do you think the list of installed files? Or do you want list of files *before* install?

Comment: @uzsolt the list of installed files and the paths of those files installed in my file system. Such as, the boost-libs may be installed under `/usr/libs/` and other paths.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

pacman with the -Q flag, can display the installed location of the package. See pacman -Q --help for the respective suboptions of -Q flag.

The -Q flag is used to search for already installed packages.
The -F flag is used to search for remote packages. (as Liang Zhou mentioned)

```
pacman -Qh # Print help info
pacman -Q  boost-libs    # Display version
pacman -Ql boost-libs    # Display file list provided by local package
pacman -Qk boost-libs    # Check the local package database
pacman -Qo /path/to/file # Check if the file is owned by any package
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, explanations added.

Answer (score 72):

I am not on my arch now to check, but I bet `pacman -Ql boost-libs` or `pacman -Qk boost-libs` will do the trick by providing you with the list of files installed by the package.

Comment: Isn't `pacman -Ql` from the answer below the only thing that answers OP's question?

Comment: @ArturTagisow did you look at the dates? this question was from 2014, the post below was posted in 2017 (3 years after the OP posted the question) and edited again in 2020. yes the answer below has a better answer at this time but I would say he is pretty late to the party. the OP probably forgot about this question.

Answer (score 4):

As of today, in `pacman` v6.0, the command is slightly changed: `pacman -Fl package-name` rather than `pacman -Ql package-name`